# explanation of ssh tunnel and forwarding options

Tags: ssh, tunnel

I can't seem to figure out the difference between the ssh options -L -D -W and -w .. They all appear to offer some variation of tunneling, but I'm not too proficient in networking, and the manpage doesn't offer much.  Can somebody point me in the direction of a thorough layman's explanation of this, or offer one here?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some example use cases. I have used the first and the second, and think I understand the third. The last one is new to me, but this seems roughly right for it.

### ssh -D 1234 tess@remotecomputer

> Connect to remotecomputer and log in as me.
>
> SSH Client opens port 1234 on my local workstation and starts listening as a [SOCKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) proxy.
>
> I open FireFox on my local workstation and configure it to use a SOCKS proxy, "localhost:1234".
>
> Browsing the web, Firefox connects to my local workstation port 1234, SSH client accepts the connection. Passes the traffic over the SSH tunnel to the remotecomputer. SSH Server on remotecomputer sends the traffic out to any destination website I want to get to (that's the 'Dynamic' destination).
>
> Return traffic comes back to the SSH server on remotecomputer, which returns it over the SSH connection, SSH Client returns it to FireFox.
>
> Only applications that can use the SOCKS protocol as a proxy can make use of this method, but they can use it to connect to anywhere.

### ssh -L 1234:server2:3389 tess@remotecomputer

> Connect to remotecomputer and log in as me.
>
> SSH Client opens port 1234 on my local workstation as a basic TCP network listening socket.
>
> I open Remote Desktop Client on my local workstation and connect to *localhost:1234*
>
> SSH client answers the connection and sends the data over the SSH tunnel.
>
> SSH server on remotecomputer sends the traffic to *server2* port *3389* (the remote desktop port). Return trafic comes back to SSH Server and back over the SSH tunnel and out to the RDP client.
>
> This configuration is not dynamic, traffic can only go to the host and port I specified on the command line - however almost any program that uses standard TCP/IP can use this method to connect through an SSH tunnel.

### ssh -W mail:25 tess@remotecomputer

> Connect to remotecomputer and authenticate as me, but don't login - don't start the bash shell, don't run any logon scripts.
>
> Open a TCP connection from SSH Server on remotecomputer to host "mail" port 25 (SMTP)
>
> Send anything I type (or anything from my standard input) over the SSH tunnel to remotecomputer, and out to the SMTP listener on "mail".
>
> Anything it returns comes back to SSH Server on remotecomputer, back over the SSH tunnel and straight to my screen / standard output.
>
> This method is tunnelling unix pipes on the local side, and connecting them to network sockets on the remote side.

### ssh -w 5:5 tess@remotetecomputer

> Connect to remotecomputer and log in as me.
>
> SSH Client on my local workstation creates a new virtual network interface, like eth0 is a physical network interface. The new one is called tun5.
>
> I can configure tun5 like any other interface, give it an IP address.
>
> SSH Server on remotecompter also creates a new virtual network interface, tun5, which I can configure.
>
> Configure them both on the same subnet and they can talk IP over the SSH tunnel.
>
> Now I can use routing with them, use firewall rules, it looks like a VPN between the two computers / two sides, but requiring more configuration (e.g. IP routing) on the computers to make use of. The combined advantages of the -D dynamic-forwarding and the -L any-network-program-can-use-this-limited-forwarding.